# How to read an item from dynamodb in an async function (aws lambda)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

So a little background to the task, I'm trying to run the [chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) on aws lambda.

As you can see on the GitHub, it follows async/await syntax. 
My problem is, I want to be able to read a value from dynamodb in the middle of the execution of chrome-AWS-lambda.

I know how to read the value from dynamodb in normal function, I know how to use chrome-AWS-lambda. I just can't get these 2 to work together.

Should I be using some special function to read the data from dynamodb? currently, I am using DocumentClient.get()

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force the return to be a promise, and thus it will satisfy async/await requirements:

`DocumentClient.get().promise()`